# JavaScript null reference error

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a piece of code shown below that is supposed to select the first object in a list of image object. When it runs, about half of the time I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property of mylist
```

I realize that this is happening because it is trying to reference an object that has not yet been given a reference to an object. Basically, the page will load, and I want to call this function in JavaScript, however if this code runs before the list is referenced, it errors out. Here is my code snippet:

```
window.onload = function () {
       try {
            var tnl = $find('mylist');


            tnl.selectFirstItem();
       }
       catch (exception) {
            alert(exception);
       }
}
```

The

```
tnl.selectFirstItem()
```

line is the one throwing the error to the catch block.

So, my question is, is there a way to force it to wait until this object "tnl" has been referenced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "loop" you are asking for. But this is still wrong. If `tnl` is not assigned after `$find('mylist');` returns, it is not going to become assigned later. You likely have error thrown by `$find` call.

```
window.onload = function () {
  try {
    var tnl = $find('mylist');

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      if (tnl) {
        clearInterval(timer); 
        tnl.selectFirstItem();
      }
    }, 1000);

  } catch (exception) {
    alert(exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: @MattJones - beats me

Comment: Read comment I posted on other answer provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tnl = $find('mylist');
```

should be

```
var tnl = $('#mylist');
```

assuming mylist is an ID.

You're using find wrong.

First you get your element, then you use it to find a child element.
So you could do this:

```
var container = $('.containerElement');
container.find('#mylist');
```

Comment: No, I am referencing an object created in HTML with ID="mylist" that's not the issue.

Comment: It works about half the time as it is. Trust me it is not the issue.

Comment: then you have other issues.Actually, it looks like you're not providing the right code. The error is saying the variable mylist is null. Where is that variable being set at?

Comment: What is selectFirstItem()? I answered prematurely because you haven't provided us the right information on your project. What kind of javascript library are you using?

Comment: Basically, that is all irrelevant. I guess I should have worded my question better. Really what I need to know if how can I force my Javascript to loop at the line tnl.selectFirstItem(); until the tnl has been initialized?

Comment: ok let's do this. console log tnl right after you define it. Is it null?

Comment: Hi, the loop posted by @Igor fixed it. Basically, the error was occurring because this is a multithreaded program and in some cases (50%), this function was being called before the other thread had loaded the images into the list.

Comment: @MattJones - multithreaded? Is it winforms application with embedded browser control?